# Is Samsung Wallet going to support distributing tickets via email or the web?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

After reading the [Samsung Wallet documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-wallet-api), I noticed that tickets can only be distributed through an app on the device itself.

[image]

This in contrary to [Apple's Passbook](https://developer.apple.com/passbook/) where you can distribute Passes via email, the web, or directly from an app.

From the [Apple documentation on Passbook](https://developer.apple.com/passbook/Getting_Started_with_Passbook.pdf):

> An important point about distributing passes is that the user does not
>   need to have your app installed on a device in order to add your pass
>   to the Passbook library In fact, passes can exist and should be usable
>   by users without a companion app altogether. Even if you do not have
>   an app you can still create and distribute passes to users who can add
>   them via email or on the web and access them directly in Passbook.

- Am I assuming this correctly; that tickets can only be added through an App on the Samsung device?
- Is there a moment in the near future that it will be supported?
- Is there any other possibility to distribute tickets via email or the web to an Samsung device (apart from a third party app, or the customer's own app)?

Comment: Hi Jeoren, you probably won't get a lot of answers concerning this very specific issue on SO. Please try contacting the Samsung Wallet developer support directly via email: walletsupport@samsung.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nick! I did already send them an email. I was just wondering if other developers are implementing the Samsung Wallet API and how they are dealing with it.

Comment: You should remove the `passbook` tag as it not relevant to your question